# Creating a virtual network adapter on Windows to implement VPN

Tags: windows-10, networking, vpn, network-adapter

I would like to implement a custom VPN client on Windows 10 and therefore I am looking for examples how to create a virtual network adapter where I can grab all IP packets for a dedicated subnet.

I was also taking a look at OpenVPN and SoftEther but it looks like that the source code is no longer supported with Visual Studio 2019.

Answer (score 3):

The WireGuard project has [Wintun](https://www.wintun.net/), which now seems to be the preferred choice if you're looking to build a typical layer-3 VPN (carrying IPv4/IPv6 only). It was originally written for WireGuard, but is now also used by OpenVPN as well. The Wintun README specifically mentions VS 2019 as a build requirement and the source code is all in a small "wintun.c" file, so it should work as a good example.

However, the Wintun README also advises you to not build your own version at all, but instead to download the *pre-built* driver and bundle it into your application's installer – it already has the required digital signature, and this way you would avoid accidental conflicts with *other* VPN apps which make use of Wintun. (Users really don't like it when a new app breaks existing apps in a way that takes hours to fix!)

---

If you're planning to build a layer-2 VPN (carrying Ethernet), the older driver, OpenVPN's [TAP-Windows (NDIS 6)](https://github.com/OpenVPN/tap-windows6), *seems* to be compatible with modern Windows platforms as well. Its README file claims that the latest code successfully builds on Windows Server 2016 using "Microsoft Windows 10 EWDK", and the Git commit log has mentions of VS 2017 related updates. It shouldn't take much to update it for VS 2019 as well.

(Again, though, you should probably not build your own version to reduce chances of conflicts with other VPN clients that the user may have installed.)

Some other projects also carry forks of TAP-Windows, such as [ZeroTier](https://github.com/zerotier/ZeroTierOne/tree/master/windows/TapDriver6).

Comment: Thanks. Probably this is what I was looking for and good to know that also OpenVPN wants to use this

Comment: This doesn't mean TAP-Windows is going to disappear though; it will remain for those users which want a L2 (Ethernet) VPN.

Answer (score 0):

Can you take a look at this project ? http://www.tinc-vpn.org/download/ , this is a opensource project working on windows .